# WPF Datagrid Save and update same form

Tags: wpf, datagrid

When we are using WPF datagrid, I want know how to use the same form binding for adding and editing using MVVM pattern along with observable collection?

Comment: I have loaded the details to the datagrid. But I want to know how to you the same for add a new record and edit selected details from datagrid. Issue with the bindings. If I want to update details, I have to select the row then it will be loaded when I bind selectedItem.Column name! But For inserting I have to use property name.